# Silverlight COM path issues

Tags: .net, silverlight, dll, com, native

I am currently using some COM dlls with Silverlight and I am experiencing a strange issue. I had two .NET COM dlls in use that I created, both of which reference other dlls through DllImport. They were working just fine.

Then I added a third COM dll to the project. This one also references other dlls through DllImport. As soon as I create it the other two break. They throw errors saying that the other dlls they are using cannot be found. The third dll works fine however.

This is how I'm creating them

```
AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Com1");
AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Com2");
AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Com3");
```

Again if I just use Com1 and Com2 they work perfectly fine. If I add Com3 it works fine but the other two cannot find their native dlls.

I don't even call any functions on Com3, just create it and the others stop working.

Any ideas? Do you think it could be the native dll somehow? I don't understand how the third one works but the others don't, you would think they would all stop working if it was the native dll breaking something.

Comment: What are you doing to ensure that these native DLLs can be found?  If nothing then the 3rd one could do something that alters the search strategy that Windows uses, including changing the default working directory or altering the PATH environment variable.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking but I'm pretty now to COM stuff. I just have the native dll's in the same directory as the registered COM dlls. This worked fine until the third COM dll. I didn't know how the working directory was handled with COM objects. Is there a way I can be more specific about the DllImport? I just tried giving the full path as the name and it could find it.

Comment: I also tried dropping the native dlls in System32 and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to make it work. I'm still not 100% sure why this needs to be done though.

If I use Directory.SetCurrentDirectory to set the current directory to the directory with the native dlls it works.

It doesn't seem like Com3 is changing the directory but for some reason it is causing the other COM dlls to look in the current working directory instead of where they were registered.